# Springboot actuator health component check puts whole service as down?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

we have multiple health checks for our application, but if one of the components health check fails - then the status of the whole application changes to "DOWN".

What we want is the application status to still be "UP", even if a single component fails.

How to prevent a single failing component check to change the application status?

Here is an example of our health checks:

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": { "database": "MariaDB", "validationQuery": "isValid()" }
    },
    "discoveryComposite": {
      "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
      "status": "UNKNOWN",
      "components": {
        "discoveryClient": {
          "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
          "status": "UNKNOWN"
        }
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 117404147712,
        "free": 102471593984,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "linkFlow": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": { "message": "LinkFLow er tilgjengelig" }
    },
    "nissy": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": { "message": "Nissy er tilgjengelig" }
    },
    "ping": { "status": "UP" },
    "reactiveDiscoveryClients": {
      "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
      "status": "UNKNOWN",
      "components": {
        "Simple Reactive Discovery Client": {
          "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
          "status": "UNKNOWN"
        }
      }
    },
    "refreshScope": { "status": "UP" },
    "zisson": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": { "message": "Zisson API er tilgjengelig" }
    }
  }
}
```

Implementation of healthcheck:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ZissonHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    private final ZissonAPIGateway zissonAPIGateway;

    public ZissonHealthIndicator(ZissonAPIGateway zissonAPIGateway) {
        this.zissonAPIGateway = zissonAPIGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {

        if (zissonAPIGateway.isAvailable()) {
            return Health.up().withDetail("message", "Zisson API er tilgjengelig").build();
        }

        log.warn("Helsesjekk: Zisson er utilgjengelig");
        return Health.down().withDetail("message", "Zisson er ikke tilgjengelig").build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just create your own `StatusAggregator`:

```java
@Component
public class CustomHealthAggregator extends SimpleStatusAggregator {

    @Override
    public Status getAggregateStatus(Set<Status> statuses) {
        // or some othe logic here
        if (statuses.contains(Status.UP)) {
            return Status.UP;
        }
        return super.getAggregateStatus(statuses);
    }

}
```